# SQLite на  PDO в PHP

Tags: pdo, sqlite, php

Друзья ,выручайте!
Как SQLite3 поменять на PDO в этом коде ?

```
private function __construct() {

$this->rConnection = new SQLite3(APP_PATH . '/content/' . Config::get('sql'));
    }

    public function execute($sSql, $aBind = array()) {
        $oStatement = $this->rConnection->prepare($sSql);
        foreach ($aBind AS $sK => $sV) {
            $oStatement->bindValue(':' . $sK, $sV);
        }

        $this->oResult  = $oStatement->execute();       
        return $this;
    }

    public function fetchAll() {
        $aTemp      = array();
        while($a = $this->oResult->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC)) {
            $aTemp[] = $a;
        }

        return $aTemp;
    }

    public function fetch($sK = '') {
        if (strlen($sK)) {
            return a($this->oResult->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC), $sK, null);
        }
        else {
            return (array) $this->oResult->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет ничего проще. Предлагаю такой алгоритм для каждого куска SQLite3 кода:

1. Изучаете [SQLite3](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sqlite3.php)
2. Ищете чем заменить это используя [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php)
3. Появляется проблем*, а Сложность < 10* - переходите к п.1., *Сложность++*
4. Сложность => 10 - задаете вопрос

*P.S.: да, мне легче было написать это, чем лишить вас драгоценного опыта.*

Comment: Конечно опыт , это всегда хорошо , но тут срочно надо . )

Comment: да там почитать час и минимум уже можно спокойно делать, вы сюда писали столько же :)

Comment: спасибо , сделал )

Comment: прекрасная новость! и, как я вижу, без 4го пункта

Comment: угу, все оказалось гораздо проще )